# Работа с текстом,C#

Tags: c#, текст

Есть примерно следующая строка:

777?33?333?8?777?22?22?8?4?22?777?66?999?8?44?22?999?66?22?

В ней,как вы возможно заметили идут несколько чисел,а затем знак вопроса.
Возможно ли разбить эту строку на несколько частей?
Разбивать ее нужно на части до знака вопроса таким образом:

777?

33?

333?

8?

И так далее...

Заранее спасибо за ответ...

Comment: `.split('?');`, как то так..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string Data = "777?33?333?8?777?22?22?8?4?22?777?66?999?8?44?22?999?66?22?";
        foreach (var item in Data.Split('?'))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }

        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Как я уже говорил в комментарии, все это довольно легко делается через `Split`, ведь его задача и заключается в том, что бы брать и разбивать строку!

НО вы до сих пор не задали конкретной задачи, не понятно что именно вы хотите...

**К примеру:**

Для разбития строки и создания того, что хотите вы - можно поступить так:

```
 string MyString = "777?33?333?8?777?22?22?8?4?22?777?66?999?8?44?22?999?66?22?";
 var lines = MyString.Split('?');
 Console.WriteLine(string.Join("?\n", lines));
```

Тут мы разбили строку и вывели получившийся массив в нужном нам формате. Но это текст.

**Другой пример:**

```
string MyString = "777?33?333?8?777?22?22?8?4?22?777?66?999?8?44?22?999?66?22?";
var lines2 = Regex.Split(MyString, @"(?<=[?])");
```

В данном случае мы разбиваем строку через регулярное выражение и создаем массив.

Еще есть пару вариантов, но думаю это основные. Ну а [вот тот код](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9TE2MN), что в ответе.